# submit form after stripe custom checkout processes

Tags: javascript, forms, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe Custom Checkout. After a successful charge I'm trying to get a form to automatically be submitted. I know the form works but I'm not able to get the form to submit after the stripe checkout processes.

I'm pretty sure the code should go after the function(token). The stripe checkout form closes and the form is not submitting.

My form:

```
<form name="regform" id="regform" action="[[~[[*id]]]]" method="post" class="form">..Lots of data......<input type="submit" name="regform" id="regform" value="Register"> </form>
```

My Strip checkout:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
<button id="customButton">Purchase</button>
<script>
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
key: 'pk_test_zizizizizizizizizzizi',
image: '/images/VR-logo.png',
token: function(token) {
document.getElementById("regform").submit();
// Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
// You can access the token ID with `token.id`
}
});

$('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {
  var grtotal;
  grtotal = document.getElementById('total').value;
      // Open Checkout with further options
handler.open({
  name: 'Verticle Runner',
  description: '[[!+fi.pagetitle]]',
  amount: parseInt(grtotal * 100),
  email: "[[+modx.user.id:userinfo=`email`]]"
});
e.preventDefault();
});
// Close Checkout on page navigation
$(window).on('popstate', function() {
  handler.close();
});

</script>
```

Comment: So, what's the question?

Answer (score 5):

The idea here is to retrieve the card token in the `token` callback and then submit your form from there.

Let's assume you have the following form:

```
<form id="myForm" action="XXXXXX" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="stripeToken" name="stripeToken"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="stripeEmail" name="stripeEmail"/>
</form>
```

Then your call to `StripeCheckout.configure()` could be something like this:

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_XXX',
    image: '/square-image.png',
    token: function(token) {
        $("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
        $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
        $("#myForm").submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: It seems like it starts the form submit and then just stops. Is it possible that that when stripe closes it resets the page in the middle of the form submission? Could the close be delayed until after the the submit?

Comment: not it's not unless you have something else in your code doing something weird. For example the submit succeeds but your code is redirecting to the same page again because you have an error in your back end

Comment: I currently have it setup so that after the check out a submit button appears (RED) to click to submit form. This works, but I'd like to make it happen in one action. We've had a few people pay and not submit the form.

Comment: just disable the submit after the first one? You'd set a global variable that you would check before submitting so that you can't submit twice

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your submit button does NOT have a name of "submit". Took me about 6 hours to figure that one out.

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer. Since you did not provide a direct answer to the question, you shouldn't mark it as answered. This is a tip, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue.

My problem was that I had 2 buttons in the form. One of them is `type=submit`, and the other has not defined a `type`.
I fixed it defining `type=button` on that one.